# Transform a dataframe using pivot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I am trying to transform a dataframe using `pivot`. Since the column contains duplicate entries, i tried to add a `count` column following what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/8281509) (Question 10 posted in this answer).

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {
        't': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
        'input': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    df = df.drop('t', axis=1)
    df.insert(0, 'count', df.groupby('input').cumcount())
    pd.pivot(df, index='count', columns='type', values='value')
```

But I still get the same error     `raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape") ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Could someone please suggest how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you have more then one value associated with 'A' and 'B' you have to aggregate values somehow.

So if I've understood your issue right possible solution is the following:

```
#pip install pandas

import pandas as pd

d = {
        't': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
        'input': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

[image]

```
# I've used aggfunc='sum' argument for example, the default value is 'mean'
pd.pivot_table(df, index='t', columns='type', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
```

Returns

[image]